# Column stacked stock chart point placement issue

Tags: highcharts, navigator

On refining my problem statement, I came up with a column stacked stock chart.

I have set the plotOptions.series.pointPlacement to on for my application. Now the issue is that only half columns are plotted for first and last data.

```
      plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            },
            series: {            
                pointPlacement: "on"
            }
        },
```

Please refer to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbjdF/

I need to somehow make sure the entire columns are plotted without truncating the columns. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In other works, selected range in navigator should be at the start of it?

Comment: @SebastianBochan: Yeah, basically i want the selected range in navigator to be at the start of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it looks like a problem, so I reported to our developers https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1933, please stay on track with this thread.

You can add 0 values as first and last point, and add empty `categories`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vbjdF/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add type: 'category' for the xAxis instead of adding an array of empty categories